# AWS-IoT-SDK-JS-v2 connection problem - AWS CRT binary not present in any of the following locations

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I'm trying to connect to AWS IoT Core via aws-iot-sdk-js-v2 and receiving the following error when I'm running the [PubSub example](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/tree/main/samples#nodepub_sub) as described below:

```
/home/pi/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/native/binding.js:60
    throw new Error("AWS CRT binary not present in any of the following locations:\n\t" + search_paths.join('\n\t'));
    ^

Error: AWS CRT binary not present in any of the following locations:
        /home/pi/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/native/aws-crt-nodejs
        /home/pi/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-arm/aws-crt-nodejs
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/native/binding.js:60:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/native/crt.js:22:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

**I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+**

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

- Node: 14.15.3
- aws-iot-device-sdk-v2: 1.5.2
- aws-crt: 1.8.1

**I tried the solutions here [aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2 #119](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/issues/119) but nothing helped.**

**I followed [onnecting-to-existing-device](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/connecting-to-existing-device.html#gs-device-prereqs) as described in AWS IoT but still, this error occurs.**

**The commands I ran (in order after removing all was services on my raspi)** after trying the installed and updated in the following order:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
restarted by sudo shutdown -r 0
cd ~
npm install aws-crt
npm install aws-iot-device-sdk-v2
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2.git
cd ~/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2
npm install
cd ~
mkdir certs
(I copied the certs and changed the name accordingly...)
cd ~/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/samples/node/pub_sub
npm install
node dist/index.js --topic topic_1 --root-ca ~/certs/Amazon-root-CA-1.pem --cert ~/certs/device.pem.crt --key ~/certs/private.pem.key --endpoint <endpoint>
 (I swap the <endpoint> with my own....)
```

by the way [the aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/tree/main/samples)  works, but I prefer using the node.js SDK...

I opened a [new issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/issues/167) on the aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2 but I'm still waiting for an answer.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received an answer in [aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2 repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2) from [jmklix](https://github.com/jmklix) that solved my problem:

Currently, the maintainers of the package don't include the pre-compiled binaries for raspberry pi, but we can do this manually if we want.
described in [aws-crt-nodejs](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-nodejs):

```
git clone https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-nodejs.git
cd aws-crt-nodejs
git submodule update --init
npm install
```

Then we need to copy the aws-crt-nodejs.node to the location to the location mentioned in the error message:

```
cp -r ~/aws-crt-nodejs/dist/bin/linux-arm ~/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-arm
```

fixed my issue.

Comment: for anyone using 64bit Raspberry PI, aws-crt v1.8.5 now come with linux-arm64(aarch64) binary https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-nodejs/releases/tag/v1.8.5

Comment: If `npm install` fails with "CMake executable is not found", run `sudo apt install cmake`.